# SQLite DB file handle is never closed C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, file, delete-file, handle

I am trying to delete a SQLite database file from my C# application. The same application performs multiple RW queries to the DB by creating and disposing a new connection each time.

When trying to delete the DB, (on a moment when I can assure the program is not querying the DB, thus no active connections) I was facing the error:

```
IOException: The process cannot gain access to <filename> because is being used by another process.
```

I have investigated for several hours: my code, SO questions, using procmon and resmon to be sure that my process was the only one holding an active handle to the file.

After all this, I determined that the DB file is not being closed correctly whenever I create a DB connection. Explanation follows:

I have the following function to perform a query and load the results into a `DataTable`:

```cs
public DataTable PerformQuery(string query) {
    try {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using(SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connString)) {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            connection.Open();
            if (!query.StartsWith("SELECT")) {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } else {
                SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                FillTable(reader, table);
            }
            // Despite using the using scope, close and dispose the connection manually
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
        // Kill all pools and call GC
        SQLiteConnection.ClearAllPools();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        return table;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Handle error... (not relevant)
        return null;
    }
}
```

Well, using SysInternals `handle.exe` in an infinite loop (running every second) and debugging the program step-by-step using Visual Studio's Debugger I found out that the file handle to my DB file is not being closed despite:

- Calling `Close`
- Calling `Dispose`
- Getting out of the `using` scope
- Killing all pools
- Executing GC and waiting for it to finish

I really need to delete my DB file from inside the code but I cannot as the file handle is never closed.

How could I solve this?

EDIT 1:

- Using .NET Winforms Application with `System.Data.SQLite`
- Already tried adding `Pooling=false` to the connection string.

Comment: Is this .NET Framework, EFCore, what?

Comment: .NET, Winform App. Using `System.Data.SQLite`.

Comment: Try adding "Pooling=false" to your connection string. That is, don't use connection pooling.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I have tried this but also without success.

Comment: SQLiteCommand is also disposable. Try disposing it.

Comment: Same disposing stuff to SQLiteDataReader

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to close the SQLiteCommand  as well?

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connString)) {
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand()){
        // do stuff here
    }
}
SQLiteConnection.ClearAllPools();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ClearAllPools() is needed so that the SqliteDB FileHandles are relieved (when Connection Pooling is used)